# Memory leak in Play Framework(2.4.6, Scala) application

Tags: java, scala, memory-management, memory-leaks, playframework

I have service written in scala play framework 2.4.6. I observed that memory usage my services are increasing day by day(1% per day), I haven't get OutOfMemoryError yet.
As service is running on production server I decided to run same build on dev server and profile it with jprofiler.
Following are observations(same build on dev server):

- Memory usage keep increasing and at some point memory usage gets
  reduced and again same pattern is repeated.
- Each time when memory usage reach around 320 MB, memory usage gets
  reduced(I think GC cleans memory).

However, on production memory usage are increasing continuously. While running these services I have set following configurations:

- On dev, I have set: -J-Xms1G -J-Xmx1G
- On prod, I have set: -J-Xms2G -J-Xmx8G

I want to know what if -Xms and -Xms paramter values controls GC behaviour.
In case there is memory leak in my play application, how can I find out source for memory leak?

Comment: That does not look like a memory leak in any way.

Comment: And you can get some idea about how to check for mem-leaks from [this blog](https://www.toptal.com/java/hunting-memory-leaks-in-java)

Comment: Why it doesn't look like memory leak? Memory usage are increasing day by day and number of requests are constant.

Comment: The heap size of your production environment is 8 times larger than the one of your dev environment. It's totally normal that garbage collection occurs less frequently in this scenario. What's the current memory usage?

Comment: When service was started(before 7 days), memory usage was 1.4 GB. Now its 2.4 GB. Per day memory usage increase by 1%. I am checking memory usage with top command.

Comment: I agree that heap parameters differ in dev and prod environment. Does GC gets invoked based on values of these parameters?

Comment: @fxlae: I see that when heap memory reaches around 2.5 GB on production, heap usage dropped. However, residual memory(used by java process) was not reduced. I am curious why residual memory is not freed when heap memory was freed.

Comment: Unless it's not growing steadily, there is no problem. Observe it for a while.

Comment: @fxlae: Yes, it is growing steadily. Residual memory increases by 1% each day.